# How To Get Fixed Timezone For All Location

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, time, timezone

I am using

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('asia/jakarta');
    $time = time();
    $time_lanch = (strtotime($rest['launchdate']));
    $time_lanch_sedule = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($rest['launchdate']));   

    $video_start_time = date("m/d/Y h:i:s A T",$time_lanch);  

    $time_intervel = (strtotime($rest['intervaltime']));    
?>
```

It shows jakarta time..But when i open mysite from another location or  country the time will be change..In jakarta the time show 00 days 02:18:23 left but in india there are 00 days 03:47:05 left..Means different country show different time....How can i fix the problem...

Comment: Please take some time in future to format your post before posting it... it was all over the place. I've edited it now, but you should do so yourself in future.

Comment: It's also unclear why you've tagged this `javascript` - what does this have to do with Javascript, given that you've only shown PHP?

Answer (score 1):

`date_default_timezone_set('asia/jakarta');` - This will set the timezone for `'asia/jakarta'`. It actually set the time for the application on server side (The server where your application is being hosted).

If you want to display the time on client side then it is better to get the tim using `Javascript`. It will actually display the time for the client machine (The `timezone` where the client machine is).